# Why can`t Blender move appended objects normally?

Tags: append, axis

Every group of objects I append from another project can't be moved in a normal way. It CAN move normally only on X axis but if I want Y or Z, every object goes it's own way, moving away from each other. Objects are NOT actually grouped (Ctrl J option), I just select them individually. Don't remember of activating smth unusual. Is there a way to change such a behavior? That`s not catastrophic but irritating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is looks like you activated local transform orientation:

[image]

in this case each object moves on it's own local axis.

If I'm not right, attach a screenshot.

Comment: Yes, it works, thanks! Strange though, can`t remember when I did it. The project is new, everything`s default. Thanks again!

Comment: maybe you pressed Alt+Spacebar